# pandas combine stock data if it falls between specific time only in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I have minute-by-minute stock data from 2017 to 2019.
I want to keep only data after 9:16 for each day
therefore I want to convert any data between 9:00 to 9:16 as value of 9:16
ie:

**value of 09:16 should be**

- `open` : value of 1st data from 9:00 - 9:16 , here 116.00
- `high` : highest value from 9:00 - 9:16, here 117.00
- `low` :  lowest value from 9:00 - 9:16, here 116.00
- `close`: this will be value at 9:16 , here 113.00

```
                       open    high     low   close
date                                               
2017-01-02 09:08:00  116.00  116.00  116.00  116.00
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.10  117.80  117.00  113.00
2017-01-02 09:17:00  115.50  116.20  115.50  116.20
2017-01-02 09:18:00  116.05  116.35  116.00  116.00
2017-01-02 09:19:00  116.00  116.00  115.60  115.75
...                     ...     ...     ...     ...
2029-12-29 15:56:00  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
2019-12-29 15:57:00  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
2019-12-29 15:58:00  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35
2019-12-29 15:59:00  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
2019-12-29 16:36:00  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
```

Here is what I tried :

```
#Get data from/to 9:00 - 9:16 and create only one data item

convertPreTrade = df.between_time("09:00", "09:16") #09:00 - 09:16

#combine modified value to original data

df.loc[df.index.strftime("%H:%M") == "09:16" , 
    ["open","high","low","close"] ] = [convertPreTrade["open"][0],
                                        convertPreTrade["high"].max(),
                                        convertPreTrade["low"].min(),
                                        convertPreTrade['close'][-1] ]
```

but this won't give me accurate data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

```
d = {'date': 'last', 'open': 'last',
     'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last'}

# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
s1 = df.between_time('09:00:00', '09:16:00')
s2 = s1.reset_index().groupby(s1.index.date).agg(d).set_index('date')

df1 = pd.concat([df.drop(s1.index), s2]).sort_index()
```

#### Details:

Use [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to filter the rows in the dataframe `df` that falls between the time `09:00` to `09:16`:

```
print(s1)
                      open   high    low  close
date                                           
2017-01-02 09:08:00  116.0  116.0  116.0  116.0
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.1  117.8  117.0  113.0
```

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group this filtered dataframe `s1` on `date` and aggregate using dictionary `d`:

```
print(s2)
                      open   high    low  close
date                                           
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.1  117.8  116.0  113.0
```

Use [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to drop the rows from the original datframe `df` that falls between the time `09:00-09:16`, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat it with `s2`, finally use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the index:

```
print(df1)
                       open    high     low   close
date                                               
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.10  117.80  116.00  113.00
2017-01-02 09:17:00  115.50  116.20  115.50  116.20
2017-01-02 09:18:00  116.05  116.35  116.00  116.00
2017-01-02 09:19:00  116.00  116.00  115.60  115.75
2019-12-29 15:57:00  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
2019-12-29 15:58:00  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35
2019-12-29 15:59:00  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
2019-12-29 16:36:00  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
2029-12-29 15:56:00  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Extract from 9:00 to 9:16. The data frames are grouped by year, month, and day and computed against the OHLC values. The logic uses your code. Finally, you add a date column at 9:16. Since we don't have all the data, we may have left out some considerations, but the basic form remains the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
date open high low close
"2017-01-02 09:08:00"  116.00  116.00  116.00  116.00
"2017-01-02 09:16:00"  116.10  117.80  117.00  113.00
"2017-01-02 09:17:00"  115.50  116.20  115.50  116.20
"2017-01-02 09:18:00"  116.05  116.35  116.00  116.00
"2017-01-02 09:19:00"  116.00  116.00  115.60  115.75
"2017-01-03 09:08:00"  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
"2017-01-03 09:09:00"  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
"2017-12-03 09:18:00"  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35
"2017-12-04 09:05:00"  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
"2017-12-04 09:22:00"  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# 9:00-9:16
df_start = df[((df['date'].dt.hour == 9) & (df['date'].dt.minute >= 0)) & ((df['date'].dt.hour == 9) & (df['date'].dt.minute <=16))]
# calculate
df_new = (df_start.groupby([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, df['date'].dt.day])
            .agg(open_first=('open', lambda x: x.iloc[0,]),
                 high_max=('high','max'),
                 low_min=('low', 'min'),
                 close_shift=('close', lambda x: x.iloc[-1,])))
df_new.index.names = ['year', 'month', 'day']
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_new['date'] = df_new['year'].astype(str)+'-'+df_new['month'].astype(str)+'-'+df_new['day'].astype(str)+' 09:16:00'

year    month   day open_first  high_max    low_min close_shift date
0   2017    1   2   116.00  117.8   116.00  113.0   2017-1-2 09:16:00
1   2017    1   3   259.35  260.0   259.35  260.0   2017-1-3 09:16:00
2   2017    12  4   260.00  260.0   260.00  260.0   2017-12-4 09:16:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Making use of @r-beginners data and added extra few lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
datetime open high low close
"2017-01-02 09:08:00"  116.00  116.00  116.00  116.00
"2017-01-02 09:16:00"  116.10  117.80  117.00  113.00
"2017-01-02 09:17:00"  115.50  116.20  115.50  116.20
"2017-01-02 09:18:00"  116.05  116.35  116.00  116.00
"2017-01-02 09:19:00"  116.00  116.00  115.60  115.75
"2017-01-03 09:08:00"  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
"2017-01-03 09:09:00"  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
"2017-01-03 09:16:00"  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
"2017-01-03 09:17:00"  261.00  261.00  261.00  261.00
"2017-01-03 09:18:00"  262.00  262.00  262.00  262.00
"2017-12-03 09:18:00"  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35
"2017-12-04 09:05:00"  260.00  260.00  260.00  260.00
"2017-12-04 09:22:00"  259.35  259.35  259.35  259.35
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
```

The code below starts the whole process. Might not be the best way to do it, but something that is quick and dirty:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df['date'] = df.index.date
dates = np.unique(df.index.date)

first_rows = df.between_time('9:16', '00:00').reset_index().groupby('date').first().set_index('datetime')
first_rows['date'] = first_rows.index.date

dffs = []
for d in dates:
    df_day = df[df['date'] == d].sort_index()
    first_bar_of_the_day = first_rows[first_rows['date'] == d].copy()
    bars_until_first = df_day.loc[df_day.index <= first_bar_of_the_day.index.values[0]]
    
    if ~first_bar_of_the_day.empty:
        first_bar_of_the_day['open'] = bars_until_first['open'].values[0]
        first_bar_of_the_day['high'] = bars_until_first['high'].max()
        first_bar_of_the_day['low'] = bars_until_first['low'].min()
        first_bar_of_the_day['close'] = bars_until_first['close'].values[-1]
    
    bars_after_first = df_day.loc[df_day.index > first_bar_of_the_day.index.values[0]]
    if len(bars_after_first) > 1:
        dff = pd.concat([first_bar_of_the_day, bars_after_first])
    else:
        dff = first_bar_of_the_day.copy()
    
    print(dff)
    dffs.append(dff)
    
combined_df = pd.concat([x for x in dffs])
print(combined_df)
```

The printed results are as follows: `dff` for different dates

```
                       open    high    low   close        date
datetime                                                      
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.00  117.80  116.0  113.00  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:17:00  115.50  116.20  115.5  116.20  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:18:00  116.05  116.35  116.0  116.00  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:19:00  116.00  116.00  115.6  115.75  2017-01-02
                       open   high     low  close        date
datetime                                                     
2017-01-03 09:16:00  259.35  260.0  259.35  260.0  2017-01-03
2017-01-03 09:17:00  261.00  261.0  261.00  261.0  2017-01-03
2017-01-03 09:18:00  262.00  262.0  262.00  262.0  2017-01-03
                      open   high     low   close        date
datetime                                                     
2017-12-03 09:18:00  260.0  260.0  259.35  259.35  2017-12-03
                      open   high     low   close        date
datetime                                                     
2017-12-04 09:22:00  260.0  260.0  259.35  259.35  2017-12-04
```

The `combined_df`

```
                       open    high     low   close        date
datetime                                                       
2017-01-02 09:16:00  116.00  117.80  116.00  113.00  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:17:00  115.50  116.20  115.50  116.20  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:18:00  116.05  116.35  116.00  116.00  2017-01-02
2017-01-02 09:19:00  116.00  116.00  115.60  115.75  2017-01-02
2017-01-03 09:16:00  259.35  260.00  259.35  260.00  2017-01-03
2017-01-03 09:17:00  261.00  261.00  261.00  261.00  2017-01-03
2017-01-03 09:18:00  262.00  262.00  262.00  262.00  2017-01-03
2017-12-03 09:18:00  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35  2017-12-03
2017-12-04 09:22:00  260.00  260.00  259.35  259.35  2017-12-04
```

Side note: I am not too sure if your way in purging the data is the best, maybe you could look at whether to completely ignore the time before 9:16am daily, or even do an analysis to check out the volatility for the first 15 minutes to decide.